# Turn Smartphone into Headlamp

Tags: substitute-tool, phone

Last night I was changing my oil and using my smartphone as a flashlight (yes it did get dirty, and no I don't care). In the midst of the job I started wishing I could strap my phone to my head and use it like a headlamp. When I finished my task I went inside and searched the internet for a smartphone attachment that would fulfill my desire, but couldn't find any. I don't believe that such a smartphone mount doesn't exist, has anyone found such a thing?

Comment: I'm not interested in making one, but if someone has, then I'm interested in what they've done.

Comment: Can't see the point - in the UK, the pound stores sell very bright led lights on a headband, meant to be worn in this way - cost is a quid... and no dirty phone either

Comment: @Bamboo, I agree. This is half pointless, but it's something you could get as a gift for your dorky father-in-law. I am mostly wondering why it hasn't been made yet, since every other conceivable smartphone attachment has been.

Comment: Well I'm guessing its not been made yet because there are already much more sensible and comfortable options to strapping a phone to one's head to use as a torch... the headlamp, not to mention the headsets synth dance groups like Chemical Brothers use, with a torch either side of the ear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bam! I found them. It occurred to me that I was searching for the wrong term. A lot more results pop up if you're looking for "smartphone head camera" or something like that. This Amazon link wont be good for long, but for those of us not from the future, here it be.

[Amazon thingy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J6KO9O8)

[Velocity Clip](http://www.velocityclip.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Use a sweatband, bandanna, or rope to make an improvised sling. Place you phone between your head and the sling.

[image]

Very crude drawing showing how to use the sling and phone

Comment: You would probably need a 3rd strap and a mount for the phone to be secure without making a tourniquet for your head.

Comment: That will depend on the shape of your head, the amount of lateral movement of the phone, and the weight of the phone.

Comment: Using tape might keep it in place better.

Answer (score 0):

As a smart phone is somewhat bigger than what would easily fit to my head, you could try attaching it to the upper part of your chest using a belt or a rope.

It will not be as flexible as when attached to the head, but it is easier to fasten more securely. And for most work, it will provide good lighting on your work area.

There does exist straps made for pulse measuring devices and/or action cameras for the chest area, although I haven't seen it for smart phones. These could possibly be adapted to work. I've only seen holders for the upper arm for smart phones.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN turn a smartphone into a headlamp if you want to.  Question if it's a good idea though.  A headlamp can be purchased cheaply and if it comes damaged whilst working on a vehicle, you can buy another cheaply.  I don't know what smartphone you have but I know that mine would cost hundreds to replace so whilst you CAN use it in this way, I personally wouldn't.

Comment: First off, mine only costs $20 to replace (yeah Cricket).

Second, lets back up a bit and ask a more fundamental question. Is a smartphone (or what 99% of its extra-phone usage is) a good idea? The answer would most likely be no, since a smartphone is basically a nice tool that has been loaded with a bunch of crap to waste your time. The less you look at your touchscreen the more you will get done. I suppose this is like an anti-life hack. A question about how can I waste more time messing with my smartphone. I don't want 1 million tools, I want 1 really cool tool with 1 million attachments.